# Cryptic Symbols & Loss of Connectivity

Tags: connection-issues

My device lost 3G Connectivity this morning and only resumed around 10AM, when it did however, this minus icon was present.

Any ideas what it is? What it means, and how to get rid of it?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this, it wasnt quite blocking mode, but close. The tablet seems to have a device to suppress icons from being shown, where the wifi toggle buttons are in task bar, there is an option entitled notifications, which when toggled on can suppress icons being present in this area.

Answer (score 1):

You might have the blocking mode enabled (it's an option available in Samsung devices). To disable this mode go to Settings > Device panel, and tap the blocking mode option to enable or disable.

Source: http://www.twelveskip.com/tutorials/android/493/samsung-galaxy-s3-what-is-blocking-mode-and-how-to-use-it